# How to fix broken Conda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am in a small cluster environment where Anaconda 4.2 is installed, however, if I go to the bin folder of Anaconda and run `conda`, it says:

> ImportError: No module named conda.cli

The content of this conda is below:

```
$ cat conda
#!/usr/bin/env python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import conda.cli

    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
```

I don't want to install conda again as I am not sure if it would ruin the existing installation which was within Cloudera's parcels management, and I doubt if I need to re-install it.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Grant, that post is the answer

Comment: Hi again Grant, I need to run conda to install R with sudo, however, `sudo conda....` gets error of: `sudo:conda:command not found`. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. `CondaIOError: IO error: Missing write permissions in: /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda`

Comment: In fact I just figured it out, I can use sudo -i to interactively run as root! Thanks.